# RPG get SFLSCROLL from mutiple format DSPF without responce wait

Tags: rpgle

In RPGLE I'm try to get the SFLSCROLL from a DSPF with multiple formats displaying. I used a read of the SFLCTL to get the SFLSCROLL but the screen is waiting for a response.
How can get it to return to the program without the wait?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

From [the manual](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzakc/rzakcmstdfsflsc.htm?lang=en): 'You use this field-level keyword in the subfile-control record format to return the relative record number of the subfile record that is at the top of the subfile when control is given back to your program.'

You could use WAITRCD() on CRTDSPF to cause a timeout, but you still need to wait for the timeout to expire.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You I did see that solution but here it was a an order issue on the display.
There is a detail screen on the top of the screen then a subfile on the bottom.
(do not ask why the detail was not in the subfile control I think they had planned for multiple details in the header area)
They were doing a write of the sflctl then exfmt for the detail.
That was not giving me the SFLRRN to check new prompt in the subfile.
I changed it to do a write of the detail exfmt of the sflctl read of detail and that got all the data for me to process with them only hitting enter once after the display occurred so I could check the prompt in the subflctl:

C                   write     dtl2
C                   exfmt     sflctl1
C                   read      dtl2